# Chart.js hover over slice get NaN percentage

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I have some trouble when trying to show the percentage of a slice when hovering over using chart.js. The part where I hover over as such:

```
var options = {
    responsive: true,
    // show percentage of slice when hover
    tooltips: {
    callbacks: {
        label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
            var allData = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data;
            var tooltipLabel = data.labels[tooltipItem.index];
            var tooltipData = allData[tooltipItem.index];
            var total = 0;
            for (var i in allData) {
                total += allData[i];
            }
            var tooltipPercentage = Math.round((tooltipData / total) * 100);
            return tooltipLabel + ': $ ' + tooltipData + ' (' + tooltipPercentage + '%)';
        }
    }
    }
};
```

I am able to plot out the chart as such:

The values are correct. But when I hover over, why is the percentage returning me NaN?

Comment: have you check the output of tooltipData / total in your loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var options = {
        responsive: true,
        // show percentage of slice when hover
        tooltips: {
        callbacks: {
            label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                var allData = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data;
                var tooltipLabel = data.labels[tooltipItem.index];
                var tooltipData = allData[tooltipItem.index];
                var total = 0;
                for (var i=0; i<allData.length; i++) {
                    total += allData[i];
                }
                var tooltipPercentage = Math.round((tooltipData / total) * 100);
                return tooltipLabel + ': $ ' + tooltipData + ' (' + tooltipPercentage + '%)';
            }
        }
        }
    };
```

Comment: How come the for loop in my question resulting in NaN? And your solution works! Thanks so much!

Comment: In your code, you are accessing the value through `var i in allData`, but then you are trying to access it as an index `total += allData[i];` which results in NaN. Thus if the value at first index is, lets say 100, you are trying to access allData[100]